# Listbox Item user control to send events to viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've created a user control which allows for inline editing of a listbox item.

It's a TextBlock and a TextBox on top of each other. On double-click of the listbox item, the TextBlock is hidden and the TextBox made visible to make editing possible.

My listbox is bound to my viewmodel's ObservableCollection property.

**Question**

I wan't to:
1. Catch the edit mode 'on' to tell the ViewModel to do something i.e. prep for editing
2. Catch the edit mode 'off' to tell the ViewModel to commit the changes/edit.

Should I use EventHandlers for this or do I give my user control a ViewModel that will then send the required tasks via Messaging?

If I use EventHandlers I would need to assign the event to the selected listbox item's user control - how would I do that?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Bytheway, instead of hiding textblock and showing TextBox try this solution

```
    <TextBox Text="Text" Width="100" Height="100">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Focusable">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner approach. How would I get the textbox to look/function like a textblock? Now all of them are editable. @michael

Comment: What is the problem? If you want textbox but with diffrent appearance you ovveride default template.